# Is there a function to clean a queue on CMSIS-RTOS2(FreeRTOS)?

Tags: arm, embedded, freertos, rtos

I'm using CMSIS-RTOS2 (an RTOS FreeRTOS based for ARM), I just want to know if there are any function to **clean** a queue (put 0 in all positions). Just it, like "reboot" the queue.

```
#include "cmsis_os.h"

osMessageQueueId_t xGPS_QueueHandle;
const osMessageQueueAttr_t xGPS_Queue_attributes = {
  .name = "xGPS_Queue"
};

xGPS_QueueHandle = osMessageQueueNew (250, sizeof(uint8_t), &xGPS_Queue_attributes);
```

Comment: A queue can be _empty_. _"put 0 in all positions"_ is not the same thing - a cleared/reset queue has _no_ "positions".

Comment: That's true @Clifford I expressed myself badly, my real intention was a reset queue! Like the function osMessageQueueReset() does! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer!

The function:
`osStatus_t osMessageQueueReset(osMessageQueueId_t mq_id)`

In my case I need to use:
`osMessageQueueReset(xGPS_QueueHandle);`

The returned variable could be:

osOK: the message queue has been rest.

osErrorParameter: parameter mq_id is NULL or invalid.

osErrorResource: the message queue is in an invalid state.

osErrorISR: osMessageQueueReset cannot be called from interrupt service routines.

More details could be found in the documentation:
https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTOS2/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__Message.html#gac6dce7f9ad132d266292c2e979d861b4